C++ Compilation on Mac M3: error: 'value' is unavailable: introduced in macOS 10.13
I try to compile C++ file on my M3 Macbook and get the following error
/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/core/function_schema.h:603:46: error: 'value' is unavailable: introduced in macOS 10.13
      auto default_val = arg.default_value().value().toIntList();
                                             ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/optional:1057:33: note: 'value' has been explicitly marked unavailable here
    constexpr value_type const& value() const&
                                
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]

I am running with anaconda on python 3.8 (or 3.11) using
gcc --version 
Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.3.9.4)

Note that The compilation works on my macbook with a i9 processor
I expect a solution for my M3 macbook

Error messages in the "something is unavailable, introduced in some-OS-version"-style generally tell you that you are trying to use functionality that's not available in the operating system that you are compiling for (which is not necessarily what you're running on, mind you). You build might specify something like "build for MacOS 10.12"

Looks related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44217316/how-do-i-use-stdoptional-in-c (but the example passes on M2 Mac with Macos Sonoma 14.4, clang++ 15.0.0 (clang-1500.3.9.4) with minor change in import (optional is no longer in experimental). Which C++ SDK are you using? (Check ls -al /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk)

I suspect getting -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 into the compiler and linker command line would solve this.  How you do that depends on the build system being used.

@Lesiak  I get    lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  14 11 mar 11:49 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -> MacOSX14.4.sdk

I get-mmacosx-version-min=10.13 into the compile and it works
